# How to adjust your story points guesstimate with your actual time capacity for the sprint

Tags: agile, scrum, estimation, capacity, user-stories

I understand that on the first part of your sprint planning, you would size the stories for example using story points and poker cards and then you estimate how many stories you can tackle on the next sprint. So let´s say you agree on working on 3 stories with a total combined of 18 story points.

Then you go ahead with the second part of the sprint planning and you start breaking those stories down into tasks. These tasks are now estimated using actual hours.

I have two questions:

1) How do you estimate the tasks in hours? do you use again poker estimating but with number of hours this time? how does the team agree on the number of hours for each task.

2) Once you estimate all tasks for the 3 stories you agreed for the sprint, you find out that the number of total hours combined for all tasks of all 3 stories is 90 hours for example. If your actual team capacity in hours is 75, how do you adjust your initial commitment of delivering 3 stories now that you realize that you don´t actually have the time to do it? Do you go back to your Product Owner (if he´s not there anymore) and tell them that you will be delivering 2 stories instead or how do you go about this?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tasks are not really estimated in hours but ideal hours. It's really hard to predict how many ideal hours will be available in a week, and it's generally not a good idea at all to infer the capacity on a sprint based on hour estimates. See for example this [Scrum Alliance blog article](http://www.scrumalliance.org/community/articles/2012/august/story-points-versus-task-hours)

> Story points and task hour comparison can be thought of as the comparison of the weight and height of an elephant. In general, a taller elephant may be heavier than a shorter one, but this is not always the case. There is no biological proof of a weight-versus-height formula, despite the common perception that more height means more weight. The same explanation applies to story points versus task hours: In general, a more complex user story (higher points) should take more hours to complete, but there are always exceptions.

Normally, tasks are tackled by a single team member (or a pair), and thus they are estimated by them, and not by the whole team.

Furthermore, tasks are re-estimated daily: the number we look for is the *number of ideal hours left to complete the task* and not the total amount. So, it is a number that can go up or down, or remain constant.

Also, tasks can be added or removed during the sprint. It's actually pretty common to discover that initial plans change. It doesn't matter, as long as the total number of hours planned represents the best current estimate of what's left to do -- it's needed for burndown charts.

In conclusion, don't mind the hours. Use them to monitor progress during the sprint but not to determine capacity. This is what points are for and the two parameters are not interchangeable as it would seem.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Does that mean that the index card containing the task won´t have a remaining time estimate associated until the team member puts the estimated remaining at the end of the day?

Comment: @lezka: if you need an estimate straight away, you can estimate during the planning meeting, of course. Just don't mix it up with sprint capacity. :-)

Comment: I am asking because I´ve seen practices where teams even count the number of hours of the team at work, factoring, people on holidays, discounting foreseen meetings or absences, etc and use this to measure the capacity in hours and hence the amount of work they´ll be able to do which may be significantly different from other weeks with less meetings or more people, etc. Of course they can apply a focus factor on top of this as appropriate according to the experience or focus of each member. I guess, overtime, teams are able to feel and estimate story points taking all this into account. Right?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, breaking into and estimating tasks is very useful and often underated.  The idea is that the team become more and more accurate as time goes on through their sprints and they inspect and adapt.  I have observed teams getting to the point where they end up completing everything in the sprint except for unforseen blockers (eg. Server down time).  The idea is that the team calculate their capacity in (hours) and then calculate the amount of tasks they need to complete ( in hours).  They can use this as a guide to make a commitment.  There is a more detailed explanation here: http://www.pashunconsulting.co.uk/team_commitment_blog.html

You can also use story points to make a commitment but the general principle is that Story points are better for long term estimation (ie. for estimating when the project will deliver).  Agile Estimating and Planning is a good book for this kind of stuff, as is the Scrum Mega Pack.

Answer (score 0):

I guess an issue come from the assumption that you are able to deliver 18 points within a sprint. What looks not right when you do an estimation in hours later. So, commit to fewer number of story points initially and after several sprints you would be able to know your actual velocity in story points per sprint.

Answer (score 0):

While breaking stories into tasks is helpful, it is not very useful to estimate those tasks.
The reason is that you will spend a lot of time doing these micro estimates and they will generally be inaccurate.

Besides, adding concrete hourly estimates forces work to fit in those estimates. 
If you underestimated you might procrastinate, if you overestimated you might skip on reviews, unit tests or other quality practices just to fit the timeline.

So in general I like to stay with one estimate level -> the one that gives the velocity.